# Autohosted SharePoint Online App - Azure account needed? Deployment? Provisioning access?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure, visual-studio-2012, office365-apps

I developed/deployed a very simple autohosted app to SharePoint Online 2013  but has a URL that looks like this. Don't click on this link.

https://1e9a4afa-c77b-460e-3375a-8eded45c2200.o365apps.net/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwhatever%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Fdev&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=2&SPProductNumber=16%2E0%2E1922%2E1221

Confused..

1. It never asked me for Azure account information, will I need one if I plan to run c# code?
2. How do I deploy this app to other site collections on SPO 2013 o365 and provision who in SPO can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install app for your SharePoint Online you should add it to App Catalog or public SharePoint App Store.

If you don't want to sell your app use App Catalog here is [info](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/use-the-app-catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-HA102772362.aspx) about that

Comment: I created and published an autohosted spo app... or so I think I did.  It needed an azure subscription which I have.  when I debug, it goes to spo, but the url points back to local (cassini I think).  If I publish it takes me to a blank azure website because I set to publish there.. since not sure where else to publish  Totally confused about deployment and how authentication will work.

Comment: To add to the confusion, the SPO app catalog wants a file you downloaded. I deployed to Azure websites - was that a wrong? :) Thanks and sorry

Comment: I was able to upload an AutoHosted App to SPO that I compiled w/o an Azure subscription.  That solution had c# code, but requires CSOM to get to SharePoint Data. I manually uploaded the APP file to the SPO App Catalog.  Can anybody else confirm this is possible? And is it possible to bind asp.net controls to CSOM SPO data from c# in solution like this only using SharePoint Online an no Azure Subscriptoin?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but I try to help. Apps can comunicate with SharePoint only by using Client Object Model. You don't need additional Azure subscription. Here you can find [instruction](http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/windows-azure-auto-provisioned-apps-for-sharepoint-2013-2) how to provision autohosted app for SPO step by step